# Cannot insert into table with types in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-insert, user-defined-types

I have a C# application and I use type to insert into a SQL Server table:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[taradodType] AS TABLE
(
    [IDP] [int] NULL,
    [date] [datetime] NULL,
    [day] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [nobatkari] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [code] [nvarchar](max) NULL
)
```

C# code :

```
SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(DBsetting.Connstring);
sqlconn.Open();

using (sqlconn)
{
    try
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("InsertTaradod", sqlconn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        SqlParameter dtparam = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@taradodType", dtreadd);
        dtparam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MessageBox.Show("Saved!");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertTaradod]
    @taradodType dbo.taradodType READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.taradod 
        SELECT * FROM @taradodType
END
```

And I don't want to insert duplicate rows into the table. So I defined an index not to insert duplicate data. But there is a problem here. If there is only 1 duplicated row in data collection. None of the data is inserted, but I want to insert other data which is not duplicated

Data :

```
    1   2017-06-20 13:28:44 1   0   1   0
    4   2017-06-22 12:18:13 1   0   1   0
    2   2017-06-22 12:49:41 1   0   1   0
    3   2017-06-22 13:15:24 1   0   1   0
    1   2017-06-22 13:50:07 1   0   1   0
    3   2017-06-24 06:56:05 1   0   1   0
    1   2017-06-24 07:02:47 1   0   1   0
    5   2017-06-24 07:29:37 1   0   1   0
    7   2017-06-24 13:18:57 1   0   1   0
    6   2017-06-24 13:19:00 1   0   1   0
    8   2017-06-24 13:19:03 1   0   1   0
    5   2017-06-24 13:19:07 1   0   1   0
    3   2017-06-24 14:35:14 1   0   1   0
    1   2017-06-24 14:38:04 1   0   1   0
    3   2017-06-25 06:45:24 1   0   1   0
    2   2017-06-25 06:54:48 1   0   1   0
    1   2017-06-25 06:56:02 1   0   1   0
    5   2017-06-25 07:51:32 1   0   1   0
    6   2017-06-25 07:57:25 1   0   1   0
    7   2017-06-25 07:57:30 1   0   1   0
    8   2017-06-25 07:57:34 1   0   1   0
    2   2017-06-25 13:03:55 1   0   1   0
    5   2017-06-25 13:26:34 1   0   1   0
    6   2017-06-25 13:32:56 1   0   1   0
    8   2017-06-25 13:33:07 1   0   1   0
    7   2017-06-25 13:33:10 1   0   1   0
    1   2017-06-25 14:38:51 1   0   1   0
    3   2017-06-25 14:39:21 1   0   1   0
    4   2017-06-28 06:44:48 1   0   1   0
    3   2017-06-28 06:45:48 1   0   1   0
    1   2017-06-28 06:59:51 1   0   1   0
    5   2017-06-28 07:21:28 1   0   1   0
    9   2017-06-28 07:38:38 1   0   1   0
    8   2017-06-28 07:49:19 1   0   1   0
    6   2017-06-28 08:11:29 1   0   1   0
    7   2017-06-28 08:11:34 1   0   1   0
    8   2017-06-28 13:32:17 1   0   1   0
    9   2017-06-28 13:32:20 1   0   1   0
    7   2017-06-28 13:32:23 1   0   1   0
    6   2017-06-28 13:32:27 1   0   1   0
    5   2017-06-28 13:32:42 1   0   1   0
    4   2017-06-28 14:17:00 1   0   1   0
    3   2017-06-28 14:43:18 1   0   1   0
    1   2017-06-28 15:27:57 1   0   1   0
    4   2017-06-29 06:28:16 1   0   1   0
    1   2017-06-29 06:55:45 1   0   1   0
    3   2017-06-29 06:55:53 1   0   1   0
    5   2017-06-29 07:34:44 1   0   1   0
    8   2017-06-29 07:55:54 1   0   1   0
    6   2017-06-29 07:55:57 1   0   1   0
    9   2017-06-29 07:56:01 1   0   1   0
    7   2017-06-29 08:00:26 1   0   1   0
    9   2017-06-29 12:57:04 1   0   1   0
    7   2017-06-29 12:57:12 1   0   1   0
    8   2017-06-29 12:57:15 1   0   1   0
    6   2017-06-29 12:57:33 1   0   1   0
    5   2017-06-29 12:57:54 1   0   1   0
    4   2017-06-29 13:01:06 1   0   1   0
    3   2017-06-29 13:31:41 1   0   1   0
    1   2017-06-29 13:31:50 1   0   1   0
    4   2017-07-01 06:27:33 1   0   1   0
    2   2017-07-01 06:50:55 1   0   1   0
    3   2017-07-01 06:51:52 1   0   1   0
    1   2017-07-01 07:02:29 1   0   1   0
    5   2017-07-01 07:18:49 1   0   1   0
    9   2017-07-01 07:27:00 1   0   1   0
    8   2017-07-01 07:27:03 1   0   1   0
    7   2017-07-01 07:52:45 1   0   1   0
    6   2017-07-01 07:52:47 1   0   1   0
    2   2017-07-01 12:54:23 1   0   1   0
    7   2017-07-01 13:32:05 1   0   1   0
    8   2017-07-01 13:32:15 1   0   1   0
    9   2017-07-01 13:32:37 1   0   1   0
    6   2017-07-01 13:32:52 1   0   1   0
    4   2017-07-01 13:32:58 1   0   1   0
    5   2017-07-01 13:33:07 1   0   1   0
    1   2017-07-01 14:32:01 1   0   1   0
    3   2017-07-01 14:32:32 1   0   1   0
    4   2017-07-02 06:27:25 1   0   1   0
    3   2017-07-02 06:47:46 1   0   1   0
    1   2017-07-02 07:00:37 1   0   1   0
    2   2017-07-02 07:00:42 1   0   1   0
    5   2017-07-02 07:11:05 1   0   1   0
    8   2017-07-02 07:23:47 1   0   1   0
    9   2017-07-02 07:23:55 1   0   1   0
    7   2017-07-02 07:34:37 1   0   1   0
    6   2017-07-02 07:34:39 1   0   1   0
    2   2017-07-02 13:00:14 1   0   1   0
    8   2017-07-02 13:22:30 1   0   1   0
    9   2017-07-02 13:22:34 1   0   1   0
    6   2017-07-02 13:23:09 1   0   1   0
    7   2017-07-02 13:23:23 1   0   1   0
    5   2017-07-02 13:26:15 1   0   1   0
    4   2017-07-02 14:05:00 1   0   1   0
    3   2017-07-02 14:56:15 1   0   1   0
    1   2017-07-02 15:27:23 1   0   1   0
    4   2017-07-03 06:33:45 1   0   1   0
    1   2017-07-03 07:04:39 1   0   1   0
    5   2017-07-03 07:15:34 1   0   1   0
    6   2017-07-03 08:37:04 1   0   1   0
    7   2017-07-03 08:37:07 1   0   1   0
    8   2017-07-03 09:59:10 1   0   1   0
    9   2017-07-03 09:59:14 1   0   1   0
    8   2017-07-03 13:59:10 1   0   1   0
    9   2017-07-03 13:59:25 1   0   1   0
    5   2017-07-03 13:59:33 1   0   1   0
    7   2017-07-03 13:59:42 1   0   1   0
    6   2017-07-03 13:59:46 1   0   1   0
    4   2017-07-03 14:05:22 1   0   1   0
    1   2017-07-03 14:35:43 1   0   1   0
    4   2017-07-04 06:28:15 1   0   1   0
    2   2017-07-04 06:46:19 1   0   1   0
    1   2017-07-04 07:06:26 1   0   1   0
    3   2017-07-04 07:10:29 1   0   1   0
    5   2017-07-04 07:18:38 1   0   1   0
    8   2017-07-04 07:55:10 1   0   1   0
    9   2017-07-04 07:55:14 1   0   1   0
    1   2017-07-04 07:55:42 1   0   1   0
    7   2017-07-04 07:57:51 1   0   1   0
    6   2017-07-04 07:57:54 1   0   1   0
    1   2017-07-04 08:57:36 1   0   1   0
```

Index is on `ID` and `datetime`.

Comment: Why not you change `SELECT * FROM @taradodType` query to filter, and select only distinct rows for insertion.

Comment: No .the problem is that there is no duplicated row in taradodType.I mean that there is that row in table and when It want to insert duplicated data which is in taradodType it can not and none of them can be inserted because of only 1 duplicated row

Answer (score 1):

Your insert command is executing like a batch.

Your entire type is passed to the SQL Server stored procedure and it executes as a batch to insert.

In your stored procedure's `INSERT` statement, add a `NOT EXISTS` check like this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.taradod 
    SELECT Distinct * 
    FROM @taradodType a 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                      FROM dbo.taradod 
                      WHERE IDP = a.IDP 
                        AND Code = a.Code
                        ...and other conditions which decide duplicate rows for you.)
```

Alternatively, you can delete rows from `@taradodType` which already exist in `dbo.taradod` and then execute your insert statement.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you already have some data in `dbo.taradod`, and while inserting new data from `@taradodType` you want to filter out rows which are already exists in `dbo.taradod`.

You can try select query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM @taradodType t1
left outer join dbo.taradod  t2 on t1.IDP = t2.IDP
        and t1.date = t2.date
where t2.IDP is null
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest fix... Simply use the IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON option when defining the index.

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ixu_IndexName ON dbo.taradodType (IDP)
WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON) ON [PRIMARY];
```

Rather than throwing an error when a dupe is encountered, it simply omits the offending row of data and moves forward like nothing happened.

HTH, Jason

Comment: And what would DROP_EXISTING do here?

Comment: You can't alter an existing index. They have to be dropped and recreated. DROP_EXISTING = ON simply handles the DROP INDEX part automatically... It's entirely optional.