# Error 241 in SQL Server : converting to datetime from string in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, runtime-error, user-defined-types

I want to insert data from C# into SQL Server. So I created below type in SQL Server:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertTaradod]
    @taradodType dbo.taradodType  READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO dbo.taradod 
        SELECT * 
        FROM @taradodType a
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                          FROM dbo.taradod 
                          WHERE IDp = a.IDp 
                            AND (SELECT CAST(Date AS DATETIME)) = a.date)
```

In C#, I defined a datatable:

```
 DataTable dtreadd = new DataTable();

 dtreadd.Columns.Add("IDp");
 dtreadd.Columns.Add("date");
 dtreadd.Columns.Add("day");
 dtreadd.Columns.Add("nobatkari");
 dtreadd.Columns.Add("code");
```

I insert data into `dtreadd` using this code:

```
dtreadd.Clear();

for (int i = 0; i < dtja.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    dtreadd.Rows.Add(dtja.Rows[i]["IDp"].ToString(),DateTime.Parse(dtja.Rows[i]["date"].ToString()), GetDayOfWeek(GetPerDate2(dtja.Rows[i]["date"].ToString())), "", dtja.Rows[i]["code"].ToString());
}
```

and I use this code to insert data by type defined in SQL Server:

```
SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(DBsetting.Connstring);
sqlconn.Open();

using (sqlconn)
{
    try
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("InsertTaradod", sqlconn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        SqlParameter dtparam = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@taradodType", dtreadd);
        dtparam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MessageBox.Show("Inserted");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

But when I run this to insert data into the SQL Server table, I get an error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

The data for table-valued parameter `@taradodType` doesn't conform to the table type of the parameter. SQL Server error is:

> Msg 241, state: 1
>   The statement has been terminated

Please help me solve this problem

Comment: When using a .Net `DataTable` as a table valued parameter, you must make sure all columns in the `DataTable` match the user defined table type in your sql server.
Even if the names matches, you must also match the order of the columns. Please edit your question to include the user defined table type

Comment: Is this not just a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45906126/cannot-insert-into-table-with-types-in-sql-server which was also your question?

Comment: @ZoharPeled As you see every thing is ok but I don't know why I get error

Answer (score 1):

As @zohar-peled mentioned "Even if the names matches, you must also match the order of the columns"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the same user defined table type as in your other question (Thanks BugFinder!)

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[taradodType] AS TABLE
(
    [IDP] [int] NULL,
    [date] [datetime] NULL,
    [day] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [nobatkari] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [code] [nvarchar](max) NULL
)
```

Your data table should be something like this:

```
DataTable dtreadd = new DataTable();

dtreadd.Columns.Add("IDp", typeof(int));
dtreadd.Columns.Add("date", typeof(DateTime));
dtreadd.Columns.Add("day", typeof(string));
dtreadd.Columns.Add("nobatkari", typeof(string));
dtreadd.Columns.Add("code", typeof(string));
```

Comment: If I change type of date column in datatable to datetime. date is only in gerigorian fromat and cann't be converted to persian calander

Comment: Date has not format. you should use either `Date` or `DateTime2` in your user defined table type, and `DateTime` in your c# DataTable.